# PageControl disabled text on tabs - gray text

Tags: delphi

I am looking (I think) for the Windows API that I can use in my OnDrawTab event in the TPageControl component to display gray text on tabs that I choose.  I have done it in the past and from memory this is where I did (in the OnDrawTab event).  Unfortunately I don't have access to the code to look back how I did it before.

I'm sure that I used something like DrawText or TextOut or something but I was able to add a flag or format style to it which gave it the appearance of grayed out.  For the life of me I cannot find the command I used.  ODS_DISABLED flag seems to be something like what I'm after but it is a windows message handler so I'm sure I didn't use that before.  I'm not writing a component here, just handling the OnDrawTab event.

Anyone point me in the right direction?

I'm using Delphi 6.

Thanks

Jason

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the [`DrawState`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd162496(VS.85).aspx) and [`GrayString`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd144963(VS.85).aspx) functions.

```
procedure TForm1.FormClick(Sender: TObject);
var
  s: string;
begin
  s := 'testar';
  DrawState(Canvas.Handle,
            0,
            nil,
            integer(@s[1]),
            length(s),
            10,
            10,
            0,
            0,
            DST_TEXT or DSS_DISABLED)
end;
```

Comment: OK, I assume you know Swedish. If not, "testar" means "testing".

Comment: Thanks.  That's perfect.  Just what I was looking for.

Comment: +1, nice tip. I haven't noticed about those functions. thanx :)